# Is it possible to put headlines into table cells (and thereby make them show up in the navigation outliner)?

Tags: microsoft-word

At my workplace I have to work with Word documents which serve as meeting protocols and contain very long tables. Basically, a typical document has 2-4 pages of introductory text, and then the remaining 30-60 pages are one huge table with three columns and many, many rows. The table lists all the issues that have been debated during a week of meetings, so it is very long and all the cells contain text.

My problem: The table is very long, and it takes a lot of scrolling to find the specific headings.

My question: Is it possible to make the navigation outliner of a Word document link to specific rows (or cells) in a very long table? So that you can click on one line in the navigation outliner, and it takes you to, say, row #150 of table in this document? and another line in the navigation outliner takes you to row #175?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: please share what have you tried to solve your problem. Have you tried placing heading style text in your table?

Comment: @MátéJuhász - As a first question this one is pretty good. Why not take the time to write up an answer instead of a semi-sarcastic comment?

Comment: @JoeTaylor *your* comment is the one that comes across as less constructive. There's nothing wrong with Máté Juhász's answer.

Comment: @MátéJuhász After reading yours and Joe Taylor's replies it occurred to me that I had not phrased the question correctly. My apologies!! With "table of contents" I meant that navigation outliner that you can make appear on the left hand side of the program screen. (see screenshot below) In my version (Word 2010), this navigation view only shows headings that are outside of table cells. Applying Autoformatting to table cell contents was the first thing I tried - it did not work for the navigation outliner. Sorry! Any ideas? [screenshot](http://imgur.com/puB6g1I)

Comment: And, for any people out there who think having the Heading link in Table of contents is same as showing it in Navigation Pane... They are dead wrong. Why i say this, because *some people* think it achieves the same purpose, but it is NOT!!!. Navigation Pane is million times more useful when browsing the document on a computer.. and it stays on the side in one place.. and you can jump to and fro very quickly. Table of contents is only useful for a printed a document, otherwise pretty useless!!! Navigation pane is the BEST thing and that's what the user wants.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Word 2013

- Make sure you have inserted a Table of contents in your document
  using the references tab. This will update when you use the heading
  styles.
- Select the text in the table you wish to link to in your
  table of contents.
- Select one of the 3 heading styles from the home
  tab.
- Click on your table of contents and click update table. This
  heading will now appear in your table of contents

Due to the change in question the answer is now different. I've left the orignal in case it helps anyone.
According to [Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Move-around-in-a-document-using-the-Navigation-pane-394787be-bca7-459b-894e-3f8511515e55) the Navigation pane doesn’t display headings that are in tables, text boxes, or headers or footers
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that helps with the autogenerated table of contents. But in the navigation outliner the headings located in table cells won't show up. I edited the original question to make more clear what I was trying to ask.

Comment: Changed your question... making my answer wrong :-(

Comment: Sorry about that! I didn't pose the question very well in the original version, and had to change it after seeing that it didn't ask what I actually wanted to ask.